# Parallelizing `gcloud compute scp`

Tags: google-cloud-platform, file-transfer

I am moving a large number of files between GCP VM instances using `gcloud compute scp`. If I were moving the files from a storage bucket, I would use `gsutil -m cp`, with the `-m` flag allowing me to parallelize over multiple cores, vastly speeding up the process. Is a similar option available when using `gcloud compute scp`?

Comment: `gcloud compute scp` is just a wrapper around the SSH/SCP program on your system. That means `gcloud` does not actually perform the feature. I recommend selecting an SSH/SCP tool that supports parallelization. Two excellent tools are Bitvise and WinSCP and both are free.

Comment: Tip: Unless you have a high-speed network or are transferring small files, you will not see much of a speed-up with any file transfer protocol. Also, you mention multiple cores. That means your VM must have multiple cores (at least 4 vCPUs) before that affects performance to a noticeable degree. The key benefit for the programs that I mentioned is a nice GUI interface and you can queue a large number of file transfers minimizing wasted time.